# Listener seesaw.core clojure

Tags: clojure, listener, seesaw

a new to Clojure here.

I would like to share a behaviour which seems strange to me, but may be it's totally ok.
I followed the tutorial on github https://gist.github.com/daveray/1441520#file-seesaw-repl-tutorial-clj-L381 , and more precisely the part where I am supposed to add a Listener to a Label. Let's make a constructor and display helper:

```
(defn make-lb [s]
  (listbox :model (-> (symbol s) ns-publics keys sort)))
(defn display [content frame]
  (config! frame :content content)
  content)
```

This works  perfectly:

```
(def lb (make-lb "clojure.core"))
(display (scrollable lb) f)
(listen lb :selection (fn [e] (println "Selection is " (selection e))))
```

Howevever, this doesn't:

```
(def lb (scrollable (make-lb "clojure.core")))
(display lb f)
(listen lb :selection (fn [e] (println "Selection is " (selection e))))
```

Notice the different "Scrollable" emplacement.
In the second case, compilier tells me ***"Unknown event type :selection seesaw.util/illegal-Argument (utils.clj:19)"***

I don't see any reason why the first snippet works, and the second doesn't. I don't have any knowledge of Swing and/or other Java libraries

Comment: Fyi, Swing is deprecated, JavaFX took its place. JavaFX is also easier to use from Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't this work? (implied)

#### tl;dr

- `listbox` and `scrollable` return different things

#### Details

- Check out the return values of the different calls (original `make-lb` included for clarity):

```
(defn make-lb [s]
  (listbox :model (-> (symbol s) ns-publics keys sort)))

(class (make-lb "clojure.core"))
;;=> seesaw.core.proxy$javax.swing.JList$Tag$fd407141

(class (scrollable (make-lb "clojure.core")))
;;=> seesaw.core.proxy$javax.swing.JScrollPane$Tag$fd407141
```

- For our purposes, we'll just say that `listbox` returns a `JList` and `scrollable` returns a `JScrollPane`
- Given that, the calls to `display` are equivalent
- However, the calls to `listen` are *not* equivalent

  - In the first case, `lb` resolves to a `JList`, and in the second case, `lb` resolves to a `JScrollPane`

#### More details

- If we look in [the source for `seesaw.event`](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/blob/9807dab2a761589371abca15346b0b8eac5a6ab0/src/seesaw/event.clj#L523), we'd see the following:

> ; :selection is an artificial event handled specially for each class
>   ; of widget, so we hack...

- What I'll call a "real selection type" is resolved in [`resolve-event-aliases`](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/blob/9807dab2a761589371abca15346b0b8eac5a6ab0/src/seesaw/event.clj#L348)

  - You'll notice that there's a case for `JList`, but not for `JScrollPane`
- In the `JScrollPane` case, the artificial `:selection` is simply handed back from the call to `resolve-event-aliases`

  - Since this isn't a "real selection type", it's only a matter of time before things go pear-shaped
- And sure enough, [`get-or-install-handlers`](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/blob/9807dab2a761589371abca15346b0b8eac5a6ab0/src/seesaw/event.clj#L329) attempts to look up `:selection`, gets nothing back, and calls `(illegal-argument "Unknown event type %s" event-name)` where `event-name` is bound to `:selection`, which matches the exception that you were receiving